# How to prove $f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k=2^n$ without using the induction method?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

The problem is to prove the following statement for all natural numbers.
$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k=2^n$$

I already proved this using mathematical induction.
But, my instinct is telling me that there is some kind of combinatorial/algebraic method that can be used to solve this easily. (Unless my instinct is wrong.)
Can anyone give me hint on how to do this?

Comment: Well, one thing you should always do when seeking combinatorial proofs, is first to remove fractions, so multiply both sides by $2^n$ so you get that you want: $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}2^{n-k}=2^{2n}.$$

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't look like it can be simplified any further.
Are you saying that this can be used to set up a situation that connects to the above equation?

Comment: No, I'm really just saying that this is always the first step when trying to find a combinatorial proof of an identity - combinatorics is about counting, so involves whole numbers, so it can't deal with fractions.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'll keep that in mind.
(Please bear with me; I'm kind of a beginner)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t know that there’s a really easy combinatorial argument, but certainly combinatorial arguments can be made. The one that I offer below is essentially the same as **Phicar**’s (which I’ve upvoted, and which you should definitely examine), but I’ve phrased it in slightly more elementary terms and gone into more detail, given your comment about being kind of a beginner.

As **Thomas Andrews** suggested in the comments, it’s a good idea to multiply both sides by $2^n$ to get rid of the fractions. I will also use the fact that $\binom{n+k}k=\binom{n+k}n$, since having a constant lower number is likely to make life a little easier. This turns the desired identity into the equivalent identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}n2^{n-k}=2^{2n}\tag{1}$$

The most straightforward interpretation of $2^{2n}$ is that it is the number of subsets of the set $[2n]=\{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$. In that context the general term

$$\binom{n+k}n2^{n-k}$$

looks like the number of ways to choose $n$ members of the set $[n+k]$ together with any subset of $[2n]\setminus[n+k]=\{n+k+1,\ldots,2n\}$; every subset of $[2n]$ that has exactly $n$ elements in $[n+k]$ is counted here. There are two problems with this idea. First, even after we sum over $k$ we are counting only subsets of $[2n]$ that have at least $n$ elements, while the $2^{2n}$ on the righthand side counts *all* subsets of $[2n]$. Secondly, when we sum over $k$ we end up counting some subsets more than once. For instance, the subset $[n]$ is counted once for each $k$ from $0$ through $n$, because it has exactly $n$ members in $[n+k]$ for each $k$. Somehow we have to make $k$ tell us a bit more about the subset.

For starters, since we seem to be counting only subsets of $[2n]$ with at least $n$ elements, let’s do it right. For each $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ we’ll count the subsets of $[2n]$ that have at least $n$ elements **and** whose $n$-th element is exactly $n+k$. There are $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}$ ways to choose $n-1$ members of $[2n]$ that are smaller than $n+k$; those $n-1$ elements together with $n+k$ itself give us a set of $n$ elements of $[2n]$ whose $n$-th element is $n+k$, and we can then pad that with any subset of $[2n]\setminus[n+k]$ and still have a subset of $[2n]$ whose $n$-th element is $n+k$. There are $n-k$ elements of $[2n]$ bigger than $n+k$, so there are $2^{n-k}$ ways to choose some set of these to throw in with our first $n$ elements, and there are therefore

$$\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}2^{n-k}$$

ways to choose at least $n$ elements of $[2n]$ so that the $n$-th is $n+k$. Summing over the possible values of $k$, we see that there are exactly

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}2^{n-k}\tag{2}$$

subsets of $[2n]$ with **at least** $n$ elements.

To finish the job of counting subsets of $[2n]$, we need to count the subsets that have **fewer than** $n$ elements. We’d like to count these in a way that looks as much as possible like what we’ve already done, so that with luck we can combine our calculation with $(2)$ and simplify to get $(1)$. One way to do that is to count the *complements* of these sets instead, so that we’re counting the subsets of $[2n]$ that have strictly more than $n$ elements: after all, each set has a unique complement, so the total number will be the same.

Each subset of $[2n]$ with more than $n$ elements has at minimum $n+1$ elements, and we can mimic what we did before by counting them according to their $(n+1)$-st element. How many of these sets have $n+k$ as their $(n+1)$-st element? We must choose $n$ members of $[2n]$ that are smaller than $n+k$, which we can do in $\binom{n+k-1}n$ ways, and then we can throw in any subset of the $n-k$ members of $[2n]$ that are bigger than $n+k$, so there must be

$$\binom{n+k-1}n2^{n-k}$$

subsets of $[2n]$ with more than $n$ elements and whose $(n+1)$-st element is $n+k$. Summing over the possible values of $k$, we find that $[2n]$ has

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n+k-1}n2^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k-1}n2^{n-k}$$

subsets with more than $n$ elements. (Clearly $k=0$ is impossible this time, but there’s no harm in including it, since $\binom{n-1}n=0$, and the $k=0$ term therefore doesn’t change the sum anyway.) The complements of these sets are the subsets of $[2n]$ with fewer than $n$ elements, so there are

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k-1}n2^{n-k}$$

of those as well. It follows that $[2n]$ has

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}2^{n-k}+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k-1}n2^{n-k}$$

subsets.

Now just combine the two summations into one and apply Pascal’s identity, and you’re home free.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful explanation!

(This problem was intended to practice mathematical induction, but I also wanted to practice combinatorial proof.)

Comment: @Nick: You’re welcome! (I really like combinatorial proofs myself, though I have to admit that sometimes they can be quite hard to discover.)

Comment: So, if some kind of combinatorial identity involves $2^n$, then is it natural to interpret it as the number of subsets of a set with n elements?

What if it involves $3^n$ or any other exponents?

Comment: @Nick: One has to look at what else appears in the proposed identity, but certainly the first things that come to mind when I see $2^n$ are the number of subsets of an $n$-element set and the number of $n$-bit strings. The simplest interpretation of $3^n$ is as the number of $n$-character strings over the alphabet $\{0,1,2\}$, but I’d also bear in mind the possibility of rewriting it as $(2+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}k2^n$. It really is more of an art than a science, and practice — seeing lots of combinatorial arguments — helps enormously.

Comment: Well, thank you for taking your time to help me out!
I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Nick: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I tried to refrain from asking another question, but this couldn't be helped.
How would you prove the above statement algebraically without induction?
I can't think of any helpful algebraic manipulation.(I edited the question to include this.)

Comment: @Nick: I’ll give it a bit more thought, but I don’t at the moment see a purely algebraic approach.

Answer (score 4):

Keeping in mind what Andrews has told you, you know that $2^{2n}$ counts the binary strings (String as $x=x_1x_2\ldots x_{2n}$) of length $2n$ (i.e., Set $\{0,1\}^{2n}$). 
Note that you have either two possibilities for a string $x$ in that set. Either, $|x|_1\geq |x|_0$ or $|x|_1<|x|_0$, where $|x|_a$ is defined to be the number of times $a$ appears in the string. So $\{0,1\}^{2n}=A\bigcup B$, where $A=\{x\in \{0,1\}^{2n}:|x|_1\geq |x|_0\}$ and $B=\{x\in \{0,1\}^{2n}:|x|_1< |x|_0\}$ (Note that $A\bigcap B=\emptyset$, so $2^{2n}=|\{0,1\}^{2n}|=|A|+|B|$). It is not difficult to see that if $x\in A$, then $|x|_1\geq n$ so let's define a family of strings $$A_i = \left\{x\in \{0,1\}^{2n}:\sum _{k=0}^{n+i}x_k=n \wedge \sum _{k=0}^{n+i-1}x_k=n-1 \right\}\;,$$
which partitions $A$ because if $x\in A$ there must be an index $m$ such that $x_1x_2\cdots x_m$ contains $n$ 1's. and there is no prefix of it that contains $n$ 1's.

Now, $|A_i|=\binom{n+i-1}{n-1}2^{n-i}$ because we know that before $n+i$ there are $n-1$ ones, and we do not know what is after $n+i$ (there are $2n-n-i$ positions to fill). So

$$\begin{align*}|A|&=\sum _{i=0}^n |A_i|\\
&=\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{n+i-1}{n-1}2^{n-i}\\
&=\sum _{i=0}^n\left( \binom{n+i}{n}-\binom{n+i-1}{n}\right)2^{n-i}\\
&=\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{n+i}{n}2^{n-i}-\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n+i-1}{n}2^{n-i}\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the last step is by Pascal's recursion.

Note that $2^{2n}=|A|+|B|$ and $|A|=\sum _{i=0}^n \binom{n+i}{n}2^{n-i}-\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n+i-1}{n}2^{n-i}$, so if you prove $|B|=\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n+i-1}{n}2^{n-i}$ you are done.

**Hint:** Do exactly the same analysis as in $A$ but you know that, in this case, $|x|_0\geq n+1$.

Comment: Elegant solution! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generating function proof that avoids (or hides) the induction.
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k}x^n\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\binom{n+k-1}{k}+\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\right]\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k}x^n\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k+1}x^n\tag{3}\\
&=\frac12+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k+1}x^n\tag{4}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n+k-1}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k-1}x^n\tag{5}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k}x^{n+1}\tag{6}\\[9pt]
&=1+x\,f(x)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: Pascal's Triangle relation
$(3)$: substitute $k\mapsto k+1$ in the right-hand sum
$(4)$: use $\binom{2n-1}{n}\left(\frac12\right)^{2n}=\binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac12\right)^{2n+1}$ for $n\ge1$ to move $x^n$ term from the left to the right sum
$(5)$: twice $(4)$ minus $(1)$
$(6)$: substitute $n\mapsto n+1$
$(7)$: compare $(1)$ and $(6)$

Note that $(7)$ implies that
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\frac1{1-x}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\tag{8}
\end{align}
$$
Comparing the coefficients of $(1)$ and $(8)$ yields
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k}=1}\tag{9}
$$

---

**Postscript**

I think it is interesting to note that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k}{k}x^{n+k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-n-1}{k}x^{n+k}\\
&=\frac{x^n}{(1-x)^{n+1}}\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
Setting $x=\frac12$ in $(10)$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac12\right)^{n+k}=2\tag{11}
$$
Thus, exactly half of the sum resides in the first $n+1$ terms.