# I am confused on how to prove this combinations equation :(

Tags: combinations, combinatorial-proofs

**Prove that**
$\sum_{k=0}^n {n+k\choose k}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k = 2^n.$

I tried doing the following:

${n\choose 0}+\frac{n+1\choose 1}{2}+\frac{n+2\choose 2}{4}+\dots+\frac{n+n\choose n}{2^n}=2^n$
 But then I got stuck... Can someone please provide me a hint (maybe I am approaching it the wrong way?)

Comment: You've tagged this question [tag:combinatorial-proofs]. Are you specifically looking for a combinatorial proof, or would any proof do?

Comment: This is closely related to [How to prove $f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k=2^n$ without using the induction method?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1928040)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-limits-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is true for when $n=0.$ Assume the result for $n,$ and I will show the result for $n+1.$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+k+1\choose k}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k
&= 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {n+k+1\choose k}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k\\
&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {n+k\choose k}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} {n+k\choose k-1}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k\\
&=(2^k+{2n+1\choose n+1}\Big(\frac12\Big)^{n+1})+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^n{n+k+1\choose k}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k\\
&=2^k+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {n+k+1\choose k}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k,\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

so $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{n+k+1\choose k}\Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big)^k=2^{n+1}.$