# How to prove the following binomial summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

Can anyone help prove this binomial identity by using some elementary methods, and I have no clue to get started.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k} \frac{1}{2^k}=2^n$$
Wolfram Mathematica can transform the function $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k} x^k$ to something contains $\Gamma$ function and incomplete Beta-function, by using hypergeometric series, but it's not a simple method anymore.

Comment: There is an error in your equation, the right-hand side should be $2^n$.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570373/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%5Cbinom%7Bn%2Bk%7D%7Bk%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Ek%7D%3D2%5Ek%24)