# Simplifying $\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} 2^{k+1-j} \biggl(\frac{(k+1+j)!}{(k+1)!j!}\biggl) = 4^{k+1}$?

Tags: calculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

According to Wolfram Alpha,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} 2^{k+1-j} \biggl(\frac{(k+1+j)!}{(k+1)!j!}\biggl) = 4^{k+1},$$

but I don't see how this sum can be simplified to this. How is it done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll probably need to use the Binomial Theorem.

Comment: @Dan could you give me an example of how that'd be done? I'm not aware of that theorem and the web pages I'm finding on it aren't very informative for this precise case. Thanks.

Comment: A good place to start is probably to use the Binomial Theorem to get that $$4^{k+1}=(2+2)^{k+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}2^{k+1-j}2^j{k+1\choose j}$$

Comment: If only that numerator $(k + 1 + j)!$ didn't depend on the loop counter $j$.

Comment: @Lorago I see that a $\frac{1}{2^j}$ needs to factored out of the $2^{k+1}$ and into the ${k+1 \choose j}$, but I don't know how to do that. Any pointers there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n+k}{k}\frac{1}{2^k}=2^{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874816/how-to-show-sum-k-0n-binomnkk-frac12k-2n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that you found **the**  particular case of a more general problem.
$$f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}  \frac{(k+1+j)!}{(k+1)!\,j!}x^{k+1-j}$$
Using  the   Gaussian hypergeometric function for $x>1$
$$f(x)=\frac{x^{2 k+3} } {(x-1)^{k+2} }-\frac{(2 k+3)! }{x (k+1)! (k+2)!}\,\, _2F_1\left(1,2 k+4;k+3;\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
Using  the  regularized form of the Gaussian hypergeometric function

$$f(x)=\frac{x^{2 k+3} } {(x-1)^{k+2} }-\frac{2^{2 k+3} \, \Gamma \left(k+\frac{5}{2}\right)}{x\sqrt{\pi } }\,\,\, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(1,2 k+4;k+3;\frac{1}{x}\right)$$ which gives

$$f(2)=2^{2 k+3}-4^{k+1}=4^{k+1}$$

Ifif not find any other case where, for integer values of $n$
$$\sqrt[k+1] {f(x)}$$ could be an integer.